# AVPlayer SeekToTime not working. Starting from beginning everytime

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uislider, cmtime

I'm having trouble with `UISlider` and `AVPlayer` scrubbing method. Every time the method is invoked the player restarts from 0. I tried debugging and seems that the slider value is right but when I Step Over, it's set 0, thus the player restarts. This is what I've tried:

```
    var desiredTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(self.progressSlider.value), 1)

    AudioManager.sharedInstance.audioPlayer.seekToTime(desiredTime)
```

I've also tried looking at similar questions and found that it was the same when I tried their solutions.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you set the sliders minimum to 0 and the maximum to the duration of the AVAsset that you are playing?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelL. This works! But how do I update the `progressSlider.value` to the `desiredTime`? Right now it stays at the same position from where I dragged it.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the method wasn't right. You can look up in the Library.

```
var desiredTime = CMTimeMake(self.progressSlider.value *1000, 1000);
AudioManager.sharedInstance.audioPlayer.seekToTime(desiredTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated in my comment, you need to set the sliders minimum value to 0 and its maximum value to the duration of the asset being played.

To make the slider move as the player plays, add a periodic observer to the player. For example:

```
CMTime interval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(.25,1000); [_player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:NULL usingBlock:
    (CMTime time)){ NSTimeInterval t = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
         mySlider.value = t; }];
```

(You may need a weak reference to self to access `mySlider`.)
The time parameter to the block is the player's current time.

When the user slides, use seekToTime to set the players position.

One caveat: although this works, the increments of the slider will show as little jumps of the thumb. I have not figured out a simple way to make the slider move continuously - probably worth a question of its own.

Comment: What does the `(.25,1000)` mean in this example?
This is what I tried from what you said in the comment:
`let duration = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(AudioManager.sharedInstance.audioPlayer.currentItem.asset.duration))
        
        progressSlider.minimumValue = 0
        progressSlider.maximumValue = duration
        
        var desiredTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(self.progressSlider.value), 1)
        
        AudioManager.sharedInstance.audioPlayer.seekToTime(desiredTime)`. 


This is working, but then where should I implement your example?

Comment: Look at the documentation for CMTime - it explains the meaning of the parameters. 1000 is arbitrary - I use it just because it makes debugging easier. It might be better to use a number that is a multiple of 60 when you are dealing with time. As for your other question, that depends on your overall design, so I cannot answer it. I feel I have fully answered your original question. If you have more questions, please ask them as new questions.