# Setting Slider Value to Set SeekToTime in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, avplayer

I am using [Player](https://github.com/piemonte/Player) library, that is using AVPlayer & AVFoundation, which is quiet convenient for my case. I successfully managed to play the video and add a slider. I set the slider's min to 0 and max to duration of the video..

At this point, in order to connect slider to current playtime, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463369/4705339), on StackOverflow. I setup a protocol and used `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval`, so slider is linked to the currentTime and moving as video moves along successfully.

Now, here is my problem. I want to do the reverse and make - when slider moves, set currentTime of the video (forward,backward).

I made some research and I found out that it's `seekToTime` that I should link the `slider.value` (`sender.value` in my case) but, I couldn't understand how to apply it to Player. How can I make the slider to control the currentTime?

---

I am not sure if I am right, but as far as I understand, the first step should be:

```
protocol UserSetsTheTimeDelegate
{
  func userSetsTheTime(result: Int)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, PlayerDelegate {
       ...

  func sliderValueDidChange(sender:UISlider!) {
     print("value--\(sender.value)")
     self.delegate?.userSetsTheTime(sender.value)
  }
}
```

And add, I think I should add the `UserSetsTheTimeDelegate` in Player.swift, but I got confused here.

---

**Update**:

I realised that I can send the data to the Player.swift by using an instance in ViewController and adding a method in Player class. This is the first step. But now, as currentTime is getting updated (with modifying the slider) so quickly, it doesn't let me manipulate the slider value.

Comment: See the following for how to use `seekToTime`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711936/avplayer-seektotime-not-working-starting-from-beginning-everytime For how to link slider value to a function (in your case, a function implementing `seekToTime`), see my answer (using `@IBAction`) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459115/cannot-convert-value-of-type-float-to-expected-argument-cgfloat/34459130#34459130

Comment: What are the steps I should take? 1) Set the protocol in ViewController as I showed in the question. 2) Add the delegate like `public class Player: UIViewController, UserSetsTheTime {` (is this right?) 3) [Put that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31714293/4705339) as you said, but where to place it? If you can add an answer, I can accept it..

Comment: I'm sorry, I can only hint you to using the threads above to implement your current time manipulator, however not give you and exhaustive answer, hence posting as comments. Perhaps someone else can help you with a more thorough answer.

Comment: Hopefully, someone posts a detailed answer because I am so confused adapting it to Player demo. thanks for your comments tho

Comment: @senty can you share your code via dropbox so we can help? theres not much to go on here.

Comment: @Jeremie [Uploaded on GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxWHl6OLoWW6SGpBRU5wcDhNYmM/view?usp=sharing). I have just achieved one more step 2 min ago and I can manipulate the SeekToTime now but it looks quite dodgy. (Please run the project, tap on screen when video is playing and try to change the time). Also, just now, I've also found [this on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717167/how-to-enable-tap-and-slide-in-a-uislider), which looks interesting but on Obj-c unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is preferable from an UX point of view to call the `seek()` method on your `Player` after a `touchUp` on your slider, rather than whenever the value changes.

As you noticed, you had poor experience with the `sliderValueDidChange`.

Instead, try by adding a target/action on UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside (for instance) on your slider, then only seek. The experience should be better.

```
    var slider : UISlider! {
        didSet {
          slider.addTarget(self, action: Selector("touchUp:"), forControlEvents: [UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside])
        }
    }

    func touchUp(sender:AnyObject?) {
        // player.seek(slider.currentValue)
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give a more detailed answer on how to apply it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I created an instance of Player so I was able to send the data from the view controller back to Player class. Then I simply applied `seekToTime()`. At this point, visually, it was seeming poor but then I noticed that I can use `stop()`, `setCurrentTime()` and then `play()` in order to make it look nicer.