# Show video controls in subView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I want to show custom video player. Video Play successfully but controls do not show. How to show the controls as play/pause button, slider, time etc.

```
let url = fileManager.appending(videoFileNames + ".MOV")
try!AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: [])
let player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url) as URL)
let avPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
avPlayerLayer.frame = videoPlayerView.bounds
self.videoPlayerView.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
player.play()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Slider Value to Set SeekToTime in AVPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464643/setting-slider-value-to-set-seektotime-in-avplayer)

Answer (score 2):

AVPlayer don't show Controls by default ,we need to add buttons and slider and
we need to call play , pause events on AVPlayer on that button actions as like as we need to add slider for  progress by using seek function on AVPlayer.

or we can achieve by using 'AVPlayerViewController' [How to play video with AVPlayerViewController (AVKit) in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932570/how-to-play-video-with-avplayerviewcontroller-avkit-in-swift)
but we need set true for showsPlaybackControls

```
showsPlaybackControls = true
```

Comment: let  avpController = AVPlayerViewController()
        let player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url) as URL)
        avpController.player = player  //AVPlayer.init(url: urlVideoFile)
        avpController.view.frame = self.videoPlayerView.bounds
        avpController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.videoPlayerView.addSubview(avpController.view)
        self.videoPlayerView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        avpController.player?.play()

Comment: i implement this but video do not show? what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Sorry i implemet it in wrong place. Now it is working fine thanks.